# Is “Studying will help me with achieving my dreams” grammatical?

Tags: grammaticality, gerunds

I need to take sentences out of a transcript, so I can’t change the structure of this particular sentence. I can either use it in my work as a grammatically correct sentence, or I can't.

I just wanted to know whether the sentence is grammatically correct.

Answer (score 4):

It's grammatical, but it might be more usual to write:

> Studying will help me **to achieve** my dreams.

Comment: _Help_ is more likely here to take an infinitive complement (with optional _to_).

Answer (score 1):

I would eliminate *to* and make the sentence active:
    *Studying will help me achieve my dreams.*

Comment: That's how I would rephrase it as well. +1

Comment: The _to_ is optional with an infinitive complement of _help_.